# Configuration of gitlab-ci on Gitlab Omnibus 7.8.0

Tags: debian, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have installed Gitlab Omnibus (`gitlab_7.8.0-omnibus-1_amd64.deb`) on my Debian 7.

I have launched `gitlab-ci` on it.
Now I have the following message on my *gitlab-ci welcome* page.

> You need only 2 steps to set it up.
>
> 1. In the GitLab admin area under OAuth applications create a new entry. The redirect url should be http://ci.xxx.xxx/user_sessions/callback
> 2. Update the GitLab CI config with the application id and the application secret from GitLab.

So I have created the ci application entry in my gitlab, and I have added this line to my gitlab.rb:

```
gitlab_ci['gitlab_server'] = { 'url' => 'http://gitlab.xxx.xxx', 'app_id' => '3c...f4', 'app_secret' => '8a...af' }
```

I did a `gitlab-ctl reconfigure`, and no error occurred.

But I still see the welcome/configuration page on my gitlab-ci.

So what am I missing to finish my *ci <-> gitlab* link configuration ?

Comment: Can you try to update to 7.8.1? A user commented on a similar issue with the CI which was solved with 7.8.1. https://about.gitlab.com/2015/02/24/gitlab-7-8-1-released/#comment-1874403009

Comment: I have tried to upgrade in 7.8.1 but now my gitlab make 502 HTTP error on each pages... I have follow the [upgrade guide](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/update.md). So I must revert my server to 7.8

Comment: It is preferable to write about your  solution in the answer box provided - better than editing the word "solved" into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank Brian
So i have fixed this problem by upgrading to 7.8.1 (Error HTTP 502 fixed by changing right to unicorn logs)

Comment: Hi David feel free to accept your answer to show that the problem is solved.